# Shopify Fulfillment rest api integration "Required parameter missing or invalid"

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

My Payload Data is:

```
{
"fulfillment": {
"line_items_by_fulfillment_order": [
{
"fulfillment_order_id": $orderID
}
],
"tracking_info": {
"number": $trackingID,
"url": "https://ship.nimbuspost.com/shipping/tracking/". $trackingID
}
}
}
```

My API Response is:

```
{
"errors": {
"fulfillment": "Required parameter missing or invalid"
}
}
```

Not able to identify the missing parameter. please help me to identify the missing parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fulfill an order with a tracking number. To successfully fulfill and order, you need the Shopify Order ID. With that, you usually operate off of Shopify Fulfillment Orders. These also have ID you should be using. Once you try to fulfill a Fulfillment Order, you specify the line item to fulfill, with a quantity. Note that at this point, you can also provide a tracking number to be applied.

You seem to be skipping an awful of the crucial information needed. Perhaps try your efforts using a proper GraphQL query in Shopify GraphiQL, or, if you are stuck with RestAPI, ensure you match their parameters as they are clearly listed in the Fulfillment Endpoint docs.

Comment: Thanks David, I had tried but still facing same issue. Line item are optional if I want to fulfill all items in my single order.

Comment: Drop intro GraphiQL with your query and issue it like that. Will expose any issues to you. Ensure you have the correct ID too. Order ID is not the same as a fulfillment order ID.

Comment: thanks David, Now I am passing Fulfillment Order ID still am getting same error.

Comment: Keep on going! The more you work on this using GraphiQL or Insomnia, the better. Basically, you need an order, a fulfillment order ID and a tracking number and it just works! Shopify is informing you that you're missing one of the above!